# How to add total and display sum on razor view html 5?

Tags: c#, html

Total number of Bricks[enter image description here][1]

```
            <td>@Model.Brick1.Count() +@Model.Brick2.Count() + @Model.Brick3.Count() </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
   <td>@(Model.Brick1.Count() + Model.Brick2.Count() + Model.Brick3.Count()) </td>
```